# How do I define a schema for a dataframe by deriving it from a table where the custom schema is provided?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a table in RDBMS which I'm taking into a dataframe(DF1):

```
1               employee_id    
2               employee_name  
3               salary
4               designation
```

And I have a dataframe(DF2) with the following:

```
_c0   _c1       _c2        _c3
101   monali    70000      developer
102   Amy       70000      developer
103   neha      65000      tester
```

How do I define the schema for DF2 from DF1. I want DF2 to have the schema that is defined in the above table.
expected output:

```
employee_id   employee_name  salary     designation  
101           monali         70000      developer
102           Amy            70000      developer
103           neha           65000      tester
```

I want to make it parameterized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function `mapColumnNames` that takes two parameters, dataframe containing the columns (which I call `columns` dataframe) and dataframe you want to change columns' name (which I call `data` dataframe).

This function first retrieves name and id of each column in `columns` dataframe as a list of tuples. Then it iterates over this list of tuples, applying method [withColumnRenamed](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#withColumnRenamed(existingName:String,newName:String):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) on `data` dataframe on each iteration.

Then you can call this function `mapColumnNames` with `DF1` as `columns` dataframe and `DF2` as `data` dataframe.

Below the complete code:

```scala
def mapColumnNames(columns: DataFrame, data: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
  val columnNames = columns.collect().map(x => (x.getInt(0) - 1, x.getString(1)))
  columnNames.foldLeft(data)((data, columnName) => {
    data.withColumnRenamed(s"_c${columnName._1}", columnName._2)
  })
}

val output = mapColumnNames(DF1, DF2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It has worked now. I was having issues with the first column(id) as it was coming as a String. I have casted it and it's working. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

It wasn't clear what schema does your df1 holds, so used index 1 reference to fetch columns

```
val columns = df1.select($"1").collect()
```

Otherwise, we can get all the columns associated with the first dataframe

```
val columns = df1.schema.fieldNames.map(col(_))
```

and then use select with columns fetched for our new dataframe

```
val newDF = df2.select(columns :_*)
```

Comment: Thanks for that. But I'm not able to understand how we're utilizing the "columns" variable in the last part of the code.

Comment: Apologies, that was a typo. I have corrected it in the edit.

Comment: First table values,
+---+-------------+
| id|     desc_tab|
+---+-------------+
|  1|  employee_id|
|  2|employee_name|
|  3|       salary|
|  4|  designation|
+---+-------------+

Got the below error now,

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`id`' given input columns: [_c0, _c1, _c2, _c3];;
'Project ['id, 'desc_tab]
is it because of the header of table?